# How can I be sure my file stays around long enough to be shared?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

The application I'm working on allows the user to share images, which it accomplishes using an [ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) Intent. Everything works fine, unless the activity that handles the intent returns before the file is actually shared.

For example. If I share the image using Google Drive, my app receives the onActivityResult event before the file is actually sent. Since in the code that handles that event I delete the temporary file, the upload of the file to Drive fails. Is there a way to share the file without saving it? Or maybe some way to know when it has actually been sent, so it can be deleted then?

Here's some relevant code from my app.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
// ...

public static final int REQUEST_SHARE_ACTION = 1;
private File temporaryShareFile;
// ...

protected void share (Bitmap bitmap) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    if(saveTemporaryFile(bitmap)) {
        shareIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
                Uri.fromFile(this.temporaryShareFile)
        );
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"), 
                REQUEST_SHARE_ACTION
        );
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                R.string.file_save_fail_message, 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show();
    }
}

protected boolean saveTemporaryFile (Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(createTemporaryFile()) {
        return writeTemporaryFile(bitmap);
    }
    return false;
}

protected boolean createTemporaryFile() {
    this.temporaryShareFile = createFile("tmp_", ".jpg");
    if (this.temporaryShareFile != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

protected File createFile(String prefix, String suffix) {
    File outputDirectory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
            ), 
            getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
    );
    if(!outputDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        if (!outputDirectory.mkdirs()) {

        }
    }
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = File.createTempFile(
                prefix, 
                suffix, 
                outputDirectory
        );
        return file;
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        return null;
    }
}

protected boolean writeTemporaryFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
    return writeImageFile(
            this.temporaryShareFile, 
            bitmap, 
            Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 
            100
    );
}

protected boolean writeImageFile(
        File file, 
        Bitmap bitmap, 
        Bitmap.CompressFormat format, 
        int quality
) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(format, quality, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //error writing file
        Log.e("writeImageFile",e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_SHARE_ACTION) {
        temporaryShareFile.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad no.

Answer (score 0):

Are you listening for the success event? See here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file

Comment: I'm not creating the file in a Drive folder.  I'm storing the file locally, then using an ACTION_SHARE intent to share the file with Drive (or any other share provider).